# Aws eventbridge cron. Only after the nth day of the month run on weekdays

Tags: cron, aws-event-bridge

I have a billing report for aws email I send out on weekdays for anomalous overages forecasts. There's nothing useful in the couple days of the month. So I don't want to run my lambda function at all on those months. It's triggered by eventbridge.

How can I create a rule that honors this requirement?

I've tried using both day of month and day of week filters. Apparently incompatible. I've tried specifying every single day of the month with W wildcard, but that ran into length limits. It doesn't seem like a difficult requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using scheduled Rules or EventBridge scheduler? Am I understanding correctly that you want to trigger your logic basically Mo-Fr? Can you express your logic using this cron editor and paste here for clarity?

https://crontab.guru/